# Listing all products

Tags: javascript

There is a product section in my website. There is search button which you can search by product type. My problem is that it lists all the product when loading the page. What I want to do is that when you load the page I dont want to list any product at all. I want to list product just when you select product type or search spesific product.

Can you guys please help me

```js
var data = [
    //create Masterbatch-Colored Masterbatches cards
 {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PE Masterbatch",
        "manufacturer": "HECHEM",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 }, 
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PP Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
        
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PS Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "ABS Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PA Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PC Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PMMA Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PBT Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PET Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PES Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PVC Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "EVA Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "TPU Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 },
    {
  "make": "Masterbatch",
  "model": "Colored Masterbatches",
  "type": "PLA Masterbatch",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "image": "http://eukim.com/doc/no_img.png"
 }
    
];

var products = "",
 makes = "",
 models = "",
 types = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 var make = data[i].make,
  model = data[i].model,
  type = data[i].type,
        manufacturer = data[i].manufacturer,
        characteristic = data[i].characteristic,
        description = data[i].description,
  image = data[i].image;
 
 //create product cards
 products += "<div class='col-sm-4 product' data-make='" + make + "' data-model='" + model + "' data-type='" + type + "'><div class='product-inner text-center'><img src='" + image + "'><br /><div class='sol'><strong>Main Product Type&nbsp;:</strong> " + make + "<br /><strong>Product Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + model + "<br /><strong>Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + type + "<br /><strong>Manufacturer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + manufacturer + "<br /><strong>Characteristic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + characteristic + "<br /><strong>Description&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + description+ "</div></div></div>";
 
 //create dropdown of makes
 if (makes.indexOf("<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + "</option>") == -1) {
  makes += "<option value='" + make + "'>" + make + "</option>";
 }
 
 //create dropdown of models
 if (models.indexOf("<option value='" + model+"'>" + model + "</option>") == -1) {
  models += "<option value='" + model + "'>" + model + "</option>";
 }
 
 //create dropdown of types
 if (types.indexOf("<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + "</option>") == -1) {
  types += "<option value='" + type + "'>" + type + "</option>";
 }
}

$("#products").html(products);
$(".filter-make").append(makes);
$(".filter-model").append(models);
$(".filter-type").append(types);

var filtersObject = {};

//on filter change
$(".filter").on("change",function() {
 var filterName = $(this).data("filter"),
  filterVal = $(this).val();
 
 if (filterVal == "") {
  delete filtersObject[filterName];
 } else {
  filtersObject[filterName] = filterVal;
 }
 
 var filters = "";
 
 for (var key in filtersObject) {
    if (filtersObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   filters += "[data-"+key+"='"+filtersObject[key]+"']";
   }
 }
 
 if (filters == "") {
  $(".product").show();
 } else {
  $(".product").hide();
  $(".product").hide().filter(filters).show();
 }
});

//on search form submit
$("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var query = $("#search-form input").val().toLowerCase();

 $(".product").hide();
 $(".product").each(function() {
  var make = $(this).data("make").toLowerCase(),
   model = $(this).data("model").toLowerCase(),
   type = $(this).data("type").toLowerCase();

  if (make.indexOf(query) > -1 || model.indexOf(query) > -1 || type.indexOf(query) > -1) {
   $(this).show();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://eukim.com/doc/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://eukim.com/doc/filter.css"> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row" id="search">
  <form id="search-form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="filter">
  <form>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <select data-filter="make" class="filter-make filter form-control">
     <option value="">Select Main Product Type</option>
     <option value="">Show All</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <select data-filter="model" class="filter-model filter form-control">
     <option value="">Select Product Type</option>
     <option value="">Show All</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <select data-filter="type" class="filter-type filter form-control">
     <option value="">Select Type</option>
     <option value="">Show All</option>
    </select>
   </div>

  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="products">
  
 </div>
</div>

<script src="http://eukim.com/doc/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eukim.com/doc/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eukim.com/doc/products.js"></script>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: you could disable the part of the products with [CSS: display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: why load everything up front? Can you not load in products as the user's actions warrant loading those in, using `fetch()` calls for your product API?

Comment: maybe op should take a step back and start with getting all information for builing a pull down menu from scratch by avoiding `indexOf` searches for giving groups. dynamic content needs a backend which supports this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, that you should try to use a backend database (or at least a JSON file) and then fetch the data from that as needed.

However, if you want the quick-fix, it would be this (just add `style='display: none;'` to the Div as you create it) - https://jsfiddle.net/pqjd2h5a/3/

```
//create product cards
products += "<div style='display: none;' class='col-sm-4 product' data-make='" + make + "' data-model='" + model + "' data-type='" + type + "'><div class='product-inner text-center'><img src='" + image + "'><br /><div class='sol'><strong>Main Product Type&nbsp;:</strong> " + make + "<br /><strong>Product Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + model + "<br /><strong>Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + type + "<br /><strong>Manufacturer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + manufacturer + "<br /><strong>Characteristic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + characteristic + "<br /><strong>Description&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</strong> " + description+ "</div></div></div>";
```

Comment: Great, please consider marking the answer as the correct one and or voting up. I would also advise that you take a look at the Fetch API or jQuery.ajax() in order to fetch data from a backend database API or a static JSON file etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API